# Getting nodeJS web server to send form data to my email

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to get the data my nodeJS server is receiving from a form on the front end to send that data to my email. I have tried to use nodemailer and haven't succeeded much.  Can someone tell me perhaps what I am doing wrong with the following code?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/front-end"));

app.get("/", (req, resp) => {
  resp.sendFile(__dirname + "/front-end/index.html");
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post("/formData", (req, resp) => {
  const data = req.body;

  var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(
    smtpTransport({
      service: "Gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "user@gmail.com",
        pass: "123456",
      },
    })
  );

  transport.sendMail(
    {
      //email options
      from: "Sender Name <email@gmail.com>",
      to: "Receiver Name <receiver@email.com>", // receiver
      subject: "Emailing with nodemailer", // subject
      html: data, // body (var data which we've declared)
    },
    function (error, response) {
      //callback
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Message sent:");
        resp.send("success!");
      }

      transport.close();
    }
  );
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, at a glance, looks fine to me. I think the problem is (since you’re not stating you have set that up), that you want to send email with GMail. If you want to send email from your own app or web service via Gmail, you should set up a project in the Google Cloud Platform. [Read more here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs).

Alternatively, you could use a service like [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com/), which you can configure to send emails via a domain that you own. There’s a free trial. [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) is a similar service. (I’m not affiliated to either).

Comment: Awesome, had no idea that I had to setup a project in the Google Cloiud Platform! I'll be trying that later today! :D

Comment: Out of curiosity, would the lack of me configuring it on Google cloud be the reason behind why I get this weird error? I tried googling it, but don't really understand the results. Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}

Comment: That error doesn’t make much sense to me either in this context. I would expect a simple Connection refused or Not authorized, but SMTP is a strange beast. It could be that because you don't have a GCP project, the first problem GMail encounters is a missing TLS certificate, but it would be a poor developer experience (which wouldn't surprise me, but still)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this! I managed to solve it eventually... woooho